# How to handle two bus stops on both sides in gtfs stops.txt

Tags: gtfs

I am building the bus transit app using GTFS data. Suppose bus A travels from City A to B and B to A. Stop X will be on the both sides with same stop name and different coordinates.

Will i have to store the both sides of the Stop X as different records on the database?. If i store it as same record means when i show that stop on the map will show wrong coordinates.

If i store the stop as different records means, when the user searches for the stop x it will give anyone trip based on the stop id.

For this [link](https://support.google.com/transitpartners/answer/6377423?hl=en) i saw we can't use the parent station on this type of situation. If anyone know about this guide me guys.

Comment: Why You can't name the stops like "Atlanta,Bus Station" and "Boston,Bus Station"?

Comment: So stop name will be duplicate. When i have autocomplete for stop their will lot duplicate names

Answer (score 0):

`Stops.txt` should contain two records, one for each physical stop.

`Trips.txt` will contain a direction_id to distinguish between bi-directional trips with the same route_id.

`Routes.txt` will be the link between the two, assigned to each trip, and listing all stops in the given "direction".

See the [reference](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference/).

Comment: Thanks for answer. suppose i have autocomplete for the stops means, i will have duplicate name each stop. how do resolve that